# Not Got T shirt Mail Till Now from google action

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have completed my first google action project and launched it and i got a confirmation mail of review. But I did not get the T shirt link inside it. I want to tell you that I have done this project only for t shirt and i want it. I can't expect this from you. Please Resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Assistant Developer Community rewards program ended last year. Rewards are not being distributed for newly published actions.